# Flatness of certain $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, jacobian, flatness, involutions

The two-dimensional [Jacobian Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture) over $\mathbb{C}$ says the following:
Let $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfy $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q):=p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.
Then $\mathbb{C}[p,q]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Let $\beta: \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be the following involution (= automorphism of order two):
$x \mapsto x, y \mapsto -y$.

Then we can write: $p=s_1+k_1$ and $q=s_2+k_2$, where $s_1,s_2$ are symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$ and $k_1,k_2$ are skew-symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$.

It is well-know and was proved in several ways that $\mathbb{C}[p,q] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module).

> Is $\mathbb{C}[s_1,k_1,s_2,k_2] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ flat?

I am not sure if one of the known proofs for flatness of $\mathbb{C}[p,q] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ can be adjusted here.

Now I have also asked the above question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386465/a-question-related-to-the-two-dimensional-jacobian-conjecture).

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.